# Use a form to redirect the user to a specific file

Tags: php

I need to create a form for my website in which the user will type a code and will be redirected to a specific file on a folder. For example, if the user inserts "exemple" in the form, he/she will be redirected to the link mysite.com/exemple.pdf. If the code does not exist, the user would be simply redirected to an error page.

I've created the following form, but I'm not sure how to create the PHP file to redirect the user to the correct link. Can someone help me with a method for that please?

I'm not very familiar with PHP and couldn't find an example for that.

```
<form action="mysite.com/form.php" method="post">
<table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="8">
<tr>
<td width="158">Insert your code for access : </td><td width="388"><input    type="text" name="code" id="tswcode" size="25">
<input type="submit" value="Go" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I think a difficult question is: how would you keep a user from just going to `mysite.com/exemple.pdf` and downloading the file directly?

Comment: What part are you unsure about?  Do you need to start with an introductory tutorial to PHP in general?  Do you need to know how to perform a redirect?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form.php, check if a file named 'example' exists.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['code'])) {
  $filename = '/path/to/'.$_POST['code'].'.pdf';  //for example $filename = 'home/Desktop/example.pdf
  if(file_exists($filename)){
     header("Location:$filename");
} else { 
     header("Location: /path/to/error_page");
}
?>
```

Comment: Just a note: The `Location` header should have a full URL, including domain name. Most clients will probably accept relative URLs like this, but it's not strictly correct.

Comment: Also, the URL for the pdf file isn't necessarily the same as the filesystem path for it.

Comment: What you say is 100% true but I am guessing that the user that posted the question does not have any experience at all regarding php code. Of course, you can address more issues (especially security ones) but again, this is a simple and easy to understand approach.

Comment: Thank you both! I'm very new to php and I was looking for a way too start. I'll keep studying and trying to develop the code in order to address further issues, specially the security ones you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP `header` function to send HTTP headers to the client, before sending any body content. The HTTP `Location` response header is used to redirect the client to a different location. The following code illustrates this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["code"])) {
    header( "Location: http://example.com/" . $_POST["code"] . ".pdf" ) ;
} else {
?>
<form action="mysite.com/form.php" method="post">
<table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="8">
<tr>
<td width="158">Insert your code for access : </td><td width="388"><input type="text" name="code" id="tswcode" size="25">
<input type="submit" value="Go" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
} //end else
?>
```

Now, you could (and probably should) do some checking inside the `if` block to see if the code is valid, see if the user is authorized to view it, etc. As it stands now, if they enter a code that doesn't exist, then your server will just give them an ordinary 404 error page when they redirect to the non-existent pdf.